# What is meaning of taking the partial derivative of the integral of the gaussian with respect to variance?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, standard-deviation, expected-value

In order to prove that:

$E[(x- u)^2] = σ^2 $

Bishop takes the integral of the gaussian distribution (which equals 1):

$∫ N(x|μ, σ) dx = 1$

Then he takes the partial derivative with respect to ($σ^2$) and rearranges to solve for $σ^2$.

This shows that: $E[(x- u)^2] = σ^2$

I understand mathematically that this outcome is true (and I understand what a partial derivative is), but I lack the understanding of why one takes the partial derivative of the gaussian with respect to $σ^2$ (variance). What is the significance of the partial derivative with respect to variance of the gaussian distribution? What is significance of taking a partial of any probability distribution function?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think's there's a deep meaning behind differentiating a constant. I'm sure if you think long enough [something can be found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_test). However, I'd sort this into "[integration tricks](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integration-tricks/#differentiation-under-the-integral-sign)" bucket. It's routinely used in theoretical physics.

Answer (score 0):

In finance, you often use the log normal distribution to price securities, including options, which give you a right (but not an obligation) to buy a stock at a specified price by a certain date (the maturity). Option prices are functions of the price of the stock, the volatility of the stock, the so-called risk-free interest rate, and time until the maturity. The sensitivities of the option price with respect to each of those parameters are called the Greeks: the derivative with respect to price is called delta, that with respect to interest rates is called rho, with respect to time to maturity is called theta — and, to your point, the derivative with respect to the variance of the underlying security is called Vega (which, ironically, isn’t even a Greek letter).

Vega is crucial to option pricing and risk analysis. I’m more than happy to elaborate, but I hope this communicates the importance of the derivative with respect to variance.